# TypeError: current.play is not a function in React

Tags: html, reactjs, audio

I am trying to play the audio onClick in react, however I got the error, I did check the ref,
it is the audio element, I don't know what's wrong, any help will be much appreciated.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";


function App() {
  const audio = useRef(null);
  const playAudio = () => {
    let current = audio;
    console.log(current);
    current.play();
  };
  return (
    <div id="drum-machine">
      <div id="display" onClick={playAudio}>
        display
      </div>
      <div>
        
        <audio
          controls
          src="/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3"
          ref={audio}
          autoPlay
        >
          Your browser does not support the
          <code>audio</code> element.
        </audio>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`current` is a property of your ref. You need to do

```
const playAudio = () => {
    console.log(audio.current);
    audio.current.play();
  };
```

Comment: thank you it works now, I am so stupid, let current = audio; should be let {current} = audio; then it will be the same